# llamando un metodo desde otro metodo de la misma clase

Tags: java, java-swing

Tengo el siguiente problema, llamo al **metodo mostrar_usu_rol(recibe 2 objetos)** en el metodo **btb_login**,ambos metodos son de la clase **Login_usuarios**. El metodo **mostrar_usu_rol** debe mostrar el nombre y descripcion del rol de quien inicia sesion en el sistema, los datos se van a mostrar en el menu de adminis (se abre el nuevo frame del menu, cuando se inicia correctamente la sesion), el tema esta, en que, cuando se abre el frame de **menu de adminis**, no aparecen el nombre del usuario y su rol, ¿por qué no realiza su funcion el **metodo mostrar_usu_rol**, cuando lo llamo en el **metodo btb_login**?Desde ya agradeceria la ayuda;adjunto la imagen con el codigo.

***Dejo el codigo mas abajo:***

````
package Pantallas;
import Modelo.Rol_dto;
import Modelo.Usua_dao;
import Modelo.Usua_dto;
import Pantallas.Registro_nuev_usu;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Login_usuarios extends javax.swing.JFrame {
     
        
        public Login_usuarios() {
            initComponents();
         //Menú_adminis madmin=new Menú_adminis();
        }
    
        
        // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
        private void initComponents() {
    
            cont_panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
            btb_new_reg = new javax.swing.JButton();
            btb_login = new javax.swing.JButton();
            caja_passw = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
            caja_usua = new javax.swing.JTextField();
            lbl_pass = new javax.swing.JLabel();
            lbl_usua = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    
            setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    
            btb_new_reg.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 3, 14)); // NOI18N
            btb_new_reg.setText("Nuevo registro");
            btb_new_reg.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    btb_new_regActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    
            btb_login.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Trebuchet MS", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
            btb_login.setText("Loguearse");
            btb_login.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                    btb_loginActionPerformed(evt);
                }
            });
    
            caja_passw.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 2, 14)); // NOI18N
    
            caja_usua.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 2, 14)); // NOI18N
    
            lbl_pass.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 2, 14)); // NOI18N
            lbl_pass.setText("Password");
    
            lbl_usua.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Sylfaen", 2, 14)); // NOI18N
            lbl_usua.setText("Usuario");
    
            javax.swing.GroupLayout cont_panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(cont_panel);
            cont_panel.setLayout(cont_panelLayout);
            cont_panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
                cont_panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                            .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addComponent(lbl_pass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 111, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(lbl_usua, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                            .addGap(84, 84, 84)
                            .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                .addComponent(caja_passw, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(caja_usua, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 110, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(137, 137, 137)
                            .addComponent(btb_login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 125, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                    .addContainerGap(112, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, cont_panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(btb_new_reg)
                    .addGap(24, 24, 24))
            );
            cont_panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
                cont_panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lbl_usua, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(caja_usua, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                    .addGroup(cont_panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(lbl_pass, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 35, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(caja_passw, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 34, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                    .addComponent(btb_login, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGap(15, 15, 15)
                    .addComponent(btb_new_reg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 43, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addContainerGap(21, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
    
            javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
            getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
            layout.setHorizontalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addComponent(cont_panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            );
            layout.setVerticalGroup(
                layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap(28, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(cont_panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            );
    
            pack();
        }// </editor-fold>                        
    
        private void btb_loginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
            Usua_dao usudao=new Usua_dao();
            Usua_dto usudto=new Usua_dto();
            Rol_dto rdto=new Rol_dto();
            Menú_adminis madmin=new Menú_adminis();
            
            if(!caja_usua.getText().equals("")&&!caja_passw.getPassword().equals("")){
            
            usudto.setUsuario_sistema(caja_usua.getText());
            usudto.setPassword(String.valueOf(caja_passw.getPassword()));
            
            if(usudao.Loguear(usudto, rdto)){
            
              if(usudto.getId_rol()==1 && rdto.getDescripcion_rol().equals("administrador")){
              
                  
                  
                  dispose();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "bienvenido al sistema Administrador");
                  madmin.setVisible(true);
                  **this.mostrar_usu_rol(usudto, rdto);**
                >DEBERIA MOSTRAR EN EL FRAME madmin, el rol y 
                >> el usuario que ingreso al sistema en los labels
                   //madmin.rol_lbl.setText(rdto.getDescripcion_rol());
                  //madmin.usua_lbl.setText(usudto.getUsuario_sistema());
                  //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "el usuario" + " " + usudto.getUsuario_sistema()+ " " + "con el rol"+ " " + rdto.getDescripcion_rol()+ " " + "ha ingresado al sistema");
                          
                     
              }else{
              
                  dispose();
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "bienvenido al sistema usuario invitado");
              }
                
            
            }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Los datos ingresados son incorrectos, verifique los datos que ingreso");
            
            }
            
            
            
            }
            
            
            
            
        }                                         
    
        private void btb_new_regActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
            
            Registro_nuev_usu reg_usu= new Registro_nuev_usu();
            reg_usu.setVisible(true);
            
            
            
        }                                           
       
      ```public void mostrar_usu_rol(Usua_dto usudto, Rol_dto rdto){
      
       Menú_adminis madmin=new Menú_adminis();
       
      
       madmin.usua_lbl.setText(usudto.getUsuario_sistema());
       madmin.rol_lbl.setText(rdto.getDescripcion_rol());
       
       ```
       }> este es el metodo que no estaría cumpliendo su función, 
         >> cuando lo llamo en el metodo                         
         >>> **btb_loginActionPerformed**
        
        public static void main(String args[]) {
            
            java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new Login_usuarios().setVisible(true);
                }
            });
        }
    
        // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
        private javax.swing.JButton btb_login;
        private javax.swing.JButton btb_new_reg;
        private javax.swing.JPasswordField caja_passw;
        private javax.swing.JTextField caja_usua;
        private javax.swing.JPanel cont_panel;
        private javax.swing.JLabel lbl_pass;
        private javax.swing.JLabel lbl_usua;
        // End of variables declaration                   
    }
````

Comment: El código en imágenes es extremadamente dificil de leer y dificulta que otros puedan reproducir tu problema simplemente copiando y pegando. Difícilmente recibas ayuda con una publicación de este tipo. La mayoría ni se va a tomar el trabajo de teclear tu código que además es considerablemente extenso y molesto para los que usamos un tema oscuro. Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/536854/edit) y coloca el código a texto. Stack Overflow tiene resaltado de sintaxis para el código. ¡Bienvenido!

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez muchas gracias por tu comentario constructivista, no lo sabía, ya voy a modificar la pregunta, así puedo recibir la ayuda a esta inquietud, saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método no está actualizando las etiquetas del mismo objeto madmin que se muestra en el método `btb_loginActionPerformed`, sino que está creando otro objeto con el mismo nombre. Es por eso que no se ven los cambios.

Una forma simple de modificar el mismo objeto en el método `mostrar_usu_rol`, es pasárselo como parámetro.

Aconsejo respetar las convenciones en los nombres de las clases y métodos. De esta forma, al ser siempre consistente, es más fácil leer el código.

Comment: Buenas noches @Decly, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, es correcto, estaba generando otra instancia del objeto "administrador", es por eso, que no sé mostraban el nombre del usuario y su rol, cuando se abre el frame del administrador.Por otra parte, muchas gracias por tu consejo, ya puse en practica lo de las convenciones, mil gracias por tu aporte, me ha sido de gran utitlidad.

Comment: Por nada @DiegoVargas, encantado de poder ayudar. Puedes aceptar la respuesta para que la pregunta no siga como pendiente.